Calculating producer surplus when the supply function cuts the y-axis at a negative value (there is a cut-off point) in microeconomics
I want to calculate the producer surplus, should I do it from y = 0 to the equilibrium point, or from the intersection of the supply function with the y-axis to the equilibrium point, the following image shows the first option (the green polygon would be the producer surplus taking into account the first option), what is the correct way to do it?


First of all, it is unlikely that the curve ys(py) is correct. It should most likely be max(0,ys(py)) so negative values of y changed to 0. Second, is 'py' the price and if so why are you breaking economic convention of drawing the price on the second axis? This is relevant if you want to apply the standard graphical approach for calculation of CS and PS.

Consumer surplus (CS) is the area under the demand function and above equilibrium price, and Producer surplus (PS) is the area under price and above the supply function on conventional graph that has quantity on $x$ axis and price on $y$ axis.
Technically, although we omit that in speech, the CS and PS are actually areas under (above) inverse  demand (supply) function and above (below) equilibrium price.
You are shaded areas under demand and above supply intersected by equilibrium quantity. Those are not CS and PS respectively. On your picture CS and PS is located under the orange line and above zero and right of equilibrium price (assuming $p, q\geq 0$), and the PS is the area under the blue line above zero and right of equilibrium price.
I shaded those areas for you. Green is PS and blue is CS. To calculate the are of these two, since you are using linear demand and supply functions you can use formula for triangle ($A=1/2BH$), the base of triangle for PS is the difference between equilibrium and minimum price for producers to produce anything $B=p^*-p_{min}$ and  height is the equilibrium quantity $H=q^*$. For CS height is again $q^*$ and base is difference between maximum price at which demand is just equal to zero and equilibrium price $B=p_{max}-p^*$.

